# numberformatter (style currency) delete is not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, number-formatting

Below is the code I use to format a number and to reassign it back to the textfield. While deleting the text I face some issue, complete text is getting deleted instead of character by character and also I am not able to re-enter the text. Please guide me to solve this issue.

```
let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
let decimalFormatter = NumberFormatter()
var currentString = ""

func formatCurrency(_ string: String) {
    let numberFromField = (NSString(string: string).doubleValue)/100
    activeField?.text = currencyFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: numberFromField))
}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if finalTextCount >= maxCharactersLimit && string != ""{
        return false
    }

    switch string {
    case "0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9":
        currentString += string
        if textField == kmMinTextField || textField == kmMaxTextField {
            formatKms(currentString)
        } else {
            formatCurrency(currentString)
        }
    default:
        if string.characters.count == 0 && currentString.characters.count != 0 {
            currentString = String(currentString.characters.dropLast())
            if textField == kmMinTextField || textField == kmMaxTextField {
                formatKms(currentString)
            } else {
                formatCurrency(currentString)
            }
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and did not have those issues. If you are using a XIB or Storyboard, double check that 'Clear when editing begins' is not checked'

Also, I needed to set the variable to make this work:

```
var maxCharactersLimit = 10
```

and in textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String)

```
let finalTextCount = textField.text?.characters.count != nil ? textField.text!.characters.count : 0
```

Comment: "Clear when editing begins" is not checked though I face issues when I delete the text from textfield. Do I need to remove the currency symbol and separators before I delete a character?

Comment: I did not need to do this. I added numberStyle = .currency and currencySymbol = "$" for the currency formatter and after deleting characters, the textfield is $0.00. The issues you describe don't seem to be in the code you posted, perhaps elsewhere.

Comment: yes. If I keep more than one textfield then the delete is having issues. Thank you for your time. Need to debug and fix the issue.